# Disable addTarget event in a UICollectionViewCell programmatically

Tags: swift, uikit, addtarget

I have implemented a function `buttonClicked` that executes when a `UICollectionViewCell` is clicked but I want to disable it once a boolean variable is declared as "false"

```
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let actButton = UIButton()
    var isButtonEnabled = true
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        
        super.init(frame: frame)
    
        contentView.addSubview(actButton)

      //... some other constraints
            actButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        if isButtonEnabled == false  {
            actButton.removeTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .allEvents)
                                   }
    }
    
    let playerImageX = UIImage(named: PlayerX.mark)
    let playerImageO = UIImage(named: PlayerO.mark)
    
    
    @objc func buttonClicked() {
        if !isButtonEnabled{
            return
        }
        if let collectionView = superview as? UICollectionView,
            let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: self) {
            actButton.tag = indexPath.row
            if PlayerX.turn == true {
                actButton.setImage(playerImageX, for: .normal)
                PlayerX.move.append(actButton.tag) // Store the move in PlayerX's moves array
                toggleTurn(&PlayerX, &PlayerO)
            } else {
                actButton.setImage(playerImageO, for: .normal)
                PlayerO.move.append(actButton.tag) // Store the move in PlayerO's moves array
                toggleTurn(&PlayerO, &PlayerX)
            }

            if didPlayerWin(PlayerX) {
                isButtonEnabled = false
                print("Player X has won!")
                
            } else if didPlayerWin(PlayerO) {
                isButtonEnabled = false
                print("Player O has won!")
            }

            print("Button Clicked \(actButton.tag), PlayerX moves: \(PlayerX.move), PlayerO moves: \(PlayerO.move)")
        }
    }



    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I tried to disable the function direclty by adding a conditional at the begginin of the code

```
 if !isButtonEnabled{
            return
        }
```

but it still response tot he click after it is set to false so I tried to call `removeTarget` inside the constraints settings like so

```
if isButtonEnabled == false  {
            actButton.removeTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .allEvents)
        }
```

but it does not work either. Still keeps responding to the click event.

is there another method to remove addTarget()?

Comment: Cells are reusable. Make sure to reset its state overriding prepareForReuse method

Comment: I tired but still my UIButton response when it shouldn't 
override func prepareForReuse() {
          super.prepareForReuse()
        actButton.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        
      }

Comment: You should keep this info (index path enable/disable) inside your collection view controller, and every time you dequeue your cell you need to set its state before presenting it.

Comment: @willd - do you want your button to "act like a button" but not do anything? That is, when you want it disabled, should it still highlight when tapped, but NOT perform the action? Or... when you want it disabled, should it not even highlight when tapped?